# Update sql table from excel

Tags: sql, excel, insert

I need users to insert excel data into a sql table on a continuous basis.
They are not sql users, they are barely excel users.
The sprreatsheet is simple, 5 columns, less than 500 rows at a time and all into a single sql table.

In a perfect world they open and update excel and in one or two clicks get a message that says Success.

I am open to any approach.

I have used the import wizard with success, i can write vba code and some sql.

What I don't know how to do is to get a user to inseert excel into a sql table without risking the entire database to complete distruction.

stay well,

michael

Answer (score 0):

you should build a small interface program that the users would update.  You can then control it all you want, and update the database as desired, based on their input.  Add a single "SAVE" button to save their input.

Comment: oh if i were only that smart.  can you point me in the some direction for "how to build......".